# Open flutter screen from Native Method call

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

In flutter app I have impalement one native screen using platform channel. After that I want to back in flutter and open new flutter screen but I can't open the screen.

I follow below step:
1)From flutter I call Native screen by method Channel.
2)After that from native I call flutter by method channel, but in this process I get the data from native but another screen is not open.

I have implement like this:

```
  Future<dynamic> searchCallHandler(MethodCall call) async {
    switch (call.method) {
      case 'openSearch':
        print('call callMe : arguments = ${call.arguments}');
     
        navigatorKey.currentState.push(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SearchLocation()),
        );
        return Future.value('called from platform!');
      default:
        print('Unknowm method ${call.method}');
        throw MissingPluginException();
        break;
    }
  }
```

in above code get the arguments value but not go in the SearchLocation Screen of the flutter.

Comment: the same (( https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75314

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand how flutter works with native here and the activity stack.

In a flutter app, there is one main activity which extends the `FlutterActivity`. All your views and screens are drawn in this activity. So when you open your app there is just one activity (`FlutterActivity`) in the native android activity stack.

Now when you invoke a method to start a new `Activity` on the native, it spins a new `Activity` and the android native activity stack has 2 activities.

After that when you are calling:

```
navigatorKey.currentState.push(
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SearchLocation()),
);
```

through the method channel, flutter is still navigating to the the new screen in its own activity (`FlutterActivity`) which is behind the current visible native activity.

**So the solution is:**

Call `finish()` before invoking the `openSearch` method from the native end.

This will destroy the current native activity and let the `FlutterActivity` come to foreground, and you can see the search screen in flutter.

Comment: Thanks. Finish activity is working but if I don't want to finish native activity because on back press I want to see that activity. Can achieve this by other solution?